Can the constituents of a thermodynamic system be a macroscopic object
Suppose I have a macroscopic ball in a box that is stationary where the walls is the boundary of the system. Is this considered a thermodynamic system? If so I have the following questions:
1- What is the constituents of this system?
2- What would its internal energy be, would it be the kinetic energy of the ball only, if so wouldn't there be more energy due to like the temperature of the ball?
3- I know this one may seem stupid, but if internal energy is defined as the sum of the kinetic and potential energies of its constituents can I choose the granularity of its constituents (the size of the constituents since I didn't find any source talking about this)

One of the great things about thermodynamics is it really doesn't care about details at all. This is one thing that differentiates it from statistical mechanics.

@JonCuster If you could elaborate in an answer that would be great

Energy has no reference zero. Choose the reference zero you like (e.g., no movement in the frame, objects sitting at the bottom) and consider changes in energy for the processes of interest.


1- What is the constituents of this system?

Everything within the system boundaries.
Since the “walls” are material objects themselves having energy, they need to be included either as part of the system or the surroundings. Therefore you need to decide which surfaces of the walls, inside or outside surfaces, constitutes the boundary between the system and its surroundings (everything else in the universe). Then everything contained within those surfaces constitutes the system. If the wall has no openings the system is closed (no exchange of mass between the system and its surroundings).

2- What would its internal energy be, would it be the kinetic energy
of the ball only, if so wouldn't there be more energy due to like the
temperature of the ball?

The internal energy is the sum of the kinetic and potential energy of the system at the molecular level, the kinetic part related to the temperatures af the various components of the system. So it is molecular kinetic energy of the ball as indicated by its temperature, as well as anything else contained within the system boundaries.
Keep in mind that the kinetic energy of the ball due to its motion as a whole is part of the mechanical energy of the system. This is covered by the general form of the first law of thermodynamics which includes the mechanical energy of the system as well as its internal energy. The mechanical energy is the kinetic and potential energy of the system as whole due to its macroscopic motion and position with respect to an external frame of reference.

3- I know this one may seem stupid, but if internal energy is defined
as the sum of the kinetic and potential energies of its constituents
can I choose the granularity of its constituents (the size of the
constituents since I didn't find any source talking about this)

You can choose whatever granularity you want, but it depends on the objectives of your study. If you ignore molecular kinetic and potential energy and consider only the mechanical energy of the system as a whole, it’s strictly a study in mechanics, not thermodynamics.
Hope this helps.

Okay thanks but what if I didn't choose the granularity to be the molecules What if I chose chunks of them would the system of the chunks have the same energy as the original system?Note that the chunks aren't as big as the whole system just big enough to be contained within the boundaries of the system

@Johngreg The total of all the mass of the system is its total energy (mechanical plus internal), whether they are in the form of "chunks" or molecules.


Is this considered a thermodynamic system?

Yes.  The system is the gas plus the ball.

2- What would its internal energy be, would it be the kinetic energy of the ball only, if so wouldn't there be more energy due to like the temperature of the ball?

If we use the more general form of the first law of thermodynamics, we have $$\Delta U_{gas}+\Delta U_{bass}+\Delta (KE)_{ball}=Q-W$$ This form of the 1st law treats the kinetic energy separately from the thermodynamic internal energy.

I know this one may seem stupid, but if internal energy is defined as the sum of the kinetic and potential energies of its constituents can I choose the granularity of its constituents (the size of the constituents since I didn't find any source talking about this)

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by granularity, but, in general, you need to specify what you call your system in a way that makes the calculation of the parameters in the initial- and final states as simple as you can.

What I meant is suppose I have a gas would internal energy differ if I considered atoms to be constituents of the system and then calculated the energies of the atoms of I considered bigger chunks of the atoms collected together to be its constituents?If it did isn't energy conservation law violated?that's   reason for this question because if we consider the ball and box a thermodynamic system then I could make the constituents as small as I want.

You say the form of thermodynamics law treats internal energy differently from but what is internal energy ,I see internal energy defined every where by the sum of kinetic and potential energies of its constituents are they atoms or bigger chunks of them that can be as big as the ball in this example

The form I prefer is the version where internal energy includes random kinetic energy (based on deviations from the masse-mean velocity), and kinetic energy is treated separately, based on the mass mean velocity.  See Introduction to Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics by Smith and van Ness, and Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics by Moran et al.

In thermodynamics, the choice of what one considers the system is at the discretion of the analyst/modeller.
